# Is it possible to set curl to show file name before progress bar?

Tags: macos, bash, curl, progress-bar, wget

I'm trying to use curl in a script I'm developing that will download a bunch of files. I used `-#` switch with curl to force showing progress bar instead of full details which are not of interest. However, the output looks something like that:

```
######################################################################## 100.0%
######################################################################## 100.0%
######################################################################## 100.0%
```

This is not descriptive at all and I thought of adding a line before any download to show what is going to be downloaded but I did not like the result. I'm asking if there is a way for curl to output something like what we get from wget:

```
file1.zip      100%[=============================>]  33.05K  --.-KB/s   in 0.1s   
file2.zip      100%[=============================>]  46.26K  --.-KB/s   in 0.1s   
file3.zip      100%[=============================>]  19.46K  --.-KB/s   in 0.1s
```

I don't want to use wget instead, though, as it is not available for OS X by default and will require whoever going to use my script to install wget first using port or other methods which is inconvenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good way to solve this by using *curl-progress* script here (https://gist.github.com/sstephenson/4587282) which wraps curl with a custom-drawn progress bar.

By default, the script *curl-progress* does not show file name in front of the progress bar but it is totally customisable. I had to modify print_progress function so it use one additional argument which is the name of the file to be downloaded. Therefor, I modified the printf statement inside print_progress so it print the file name in suitable location before the progress bar:

```
print_progress() {
  local bytes="$1"
  local length="$2"
  local fileName="$3" # I added this third variable
  ...
  ...
  printf "\x1B[0G %-10s%-6s\x1B[7m%*s\x1B[0m%*s\x1B[1D" \
    "$fileName" "${percent}%" "$on" "" "$off" "" >&4
}
```

Now print_progress method expect three arguments and for that I modified the call to print_progress to send the third argument:

```
print_progress "$bytes" "$length" "$2"
```

Where $2 refers to the second argument sent to curl-progress. Now this is an example to download an arbitrary file from the web:

```
$ ./curl-progress -so "file1.zip" "http://download.thinkbroadband.com/20MB.zip"
```

And this is the output:
[image: Output]

I will still have to ship a copy of curl-progress script along with mine but it is better than asking the user to install wget first.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular case where curl is used to download only 1 file like given in examples in this thread, we could use this one liner function.

```
# Usage : curlp URL
curlp(){ f=${1##*/};printf "%28s%s" "" $f;COLUMNS=27 curl -# $1 -o $f ; }
```

It provide a progress bar with 20 # (i.e a # every 5% progress). You can indeed hack it to add more options, may be 2 args one is the URL the second could be the local name., etc...